# is there a way to convert an array in Ruby to a float by removing the brackets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, solr

I have a little problem that seems rather easy to solve but I can't seem to find a solution.  I'm using the Geocoder gem for Rails and from this method of:

```
Geocoder.coordinates(params[:search])
```

I'm getting an array that contains floats like this: `[43.653226, -79.3831843]`

My question is, is there a way to remove the brackets from the array or convert the value to a float so the output is `43.653226, -79.3831843`?

My closest solution so far has been to do this:

```
a = Geocoder.coordinates(params[:search])
```

and then to obtain each float individually by doing this in the method call:

```
a[0] --> 43.653226
a[-1] --> -79.3831843
```

This doesn't seem to work as I get an error with the particular method that I am trying to use.

I'm using the 'sunspot-solr' and 'sunspot-rails' gem for this and what I am trying to do is allow a user to enter a city to find users and then display users near that city within a 100, 200 km radius

This is what I have in my `user.rb` file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    searchable do
        text :city
        latlon(:location) { Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(latitude, longitude) }
    end

end
```

This is what's in my `users_controller.rb`

```
def index
    if params[:search]
      @search = User.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
        with(:location).near(*Geocoder.coordinates(params[:search]),:precision => 6)
      end
      @users = @search.results
    end
end
```

This is the line that seems to be causing the problem: `with(:location).near(*Geocoder.coordinates(params[:search]),:precision => 6)`

And finally in my view, this is the search form:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, class: "form-signin", role: "form", method: :get do %>

    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder:"Type in a location" %>

    <div><%= submit_tag "Search users", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block", id: "home-search" %></div>

<% end %>
```

Now when I'm trying to add the geospatial feature I'm getting a 400 error that looks like this:

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request Error: {'responseHeader'=>{'status'=>400,'QTime'=>2},'error'=>{'msg'=>'com.spatial4j.core.exception.InvalidShapeException: incompatible dimension (2) and values (dpz83dffmxps). Only 0 values specified','code'=>400}}
```

If anyone can help that'd me great!

Comment: Which Solr method would you like to use? How would you call it? Are you using `sunspot`?

Comment: @mdesantis I am using sunspot, I'm trying to do something like this: search = User.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
        with(:location).near(*Geocoder.coordinates(params[:search]),:precision => 6)
      end

Comment: Would you please add this info to the question? Other users would like to update their answers, since this information is useful in order to answer to your question

Comment: @mdesantis I just updated my question with more information

Comment: I don't think the line `with(:location).near(*Geocoder.coordinates(params[:search]),:precision => 6)` has problems; does the error persist using `with(:location).near(43.653226, -79.3831843, :precision => 6)`?

Comment: @mdesantis Ya even if I hard code those values in I still get the same error, I'm thinking perhaps the reason why I am getting this error is because I don't have a field that gets submitted through the query string that corresponds to the geospatial lookup in the database.  Do you think that may be the source of the error?

Comment: Frankly I have never used solr nor sunspot so I don't know how it works; anyway, I suggest you to delete this question, which is no more relevant, and open another one with the right question

Comment: the sunspot documentation does not show the use case you have in your code

Answer (score 0):

The values are floats already, if you want to use the content of the array as 2 arguments to a method call then you can use the splat operator (`*`) e.g

```
method_call(*[43.653226, -79.3831843]) is same as method_call(43.653226, -79.3831843)
```

or destructure the array and pass the new variables as argument e.g:

```
lat, lng = [43.653226, -79.3831843]
method_call(lat,lng)
```

Comment: I've tried the splat operator already, i'm thinking perhaps i'm using the geospatial feature in solr incorrectly

Comment: what kind of parameters does the method you are calling require?? and what errors are you getting

Comment: I just updated my question to include more information relevant to what I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

You could use join:
eg.

```
a = Geocoder.coordinates(params[:search])
a.join(", ");
```

Would return the array - comma separated.